# Find which season a particular date belongs to

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates and for each entry, I would like to assign a season. So for example, if a date is between 21.12. and 21.3., I would says that's `winter`. So far I have tried the following code but I couldn't make it more generic, *irrespective of the year*.

```
my.dates <- as.Date("2011-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 0:60
low.date <- as.Date("2011-12-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
high.date <- as.Date("2012-01-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

my.dates[my.dates <= high.date & my.dates >= low.date] 
 [1] "2011-12-15" "2011-12-16" "2011-12-17" "2011-12-18" "2011-12-19" "2011-12-20" "2011-12-21" "2011-12-22" "2011-12-23" "2011-12-24" "2011-12-25"
[12] "2011-12-26" "2011-12-27" "2011-12-28" "2011-12-29" "2011-12-30" "2011-12-31" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05"
[23] "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10" "2012-01-11" "2012-01-12" "2012-01-13" "2012-01-14" "2012-01-15"
```

I have tried formatting the dates without the year, but it isn't working.

```
ld <- as.Date("12-15", format = "%m-%d")
hd <- as.Date("01-15", format = "%m-%d")
my.dates[my.dates <= hd & my.dates >= ld]
```

Comment: Don't forget to put in a season-reordering switch for our friends in Oz :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  And New Zealand!  And Brazil...  As for Angelinos (LA) and seasons: there can be only one!

Comment: Note that a lot of answers here are focussing on astronomical seasons (as are commonly used in Europe). In some places (like Australia), and also commonly in science, seasons are simply defined as three-month periods (DJF, MAM< JJA, SON), as this is easier to work with (and coincidentally more accurately represents the seasons by temperature, since there is a lag from the astronomical seasons). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946955 asks the question in this sense.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

How about using something like this:

```
getSeason <- function(DATES) {
    WS <- as.Date("2012-12-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d") # Winter Solstice
    SE <- as.Date("2012-3-15",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # Spring Equinox
    SS <- as.Date("2012-6-15",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # Summer Solstice
    FE <- as.Date("2012-9-15",  format = "%Y-%m-%d") # Fall Equinox

    # Convert dates from any year to 2012 dates
    d <- as.Date(strftime(DATES, format="2012-%m-%d"))

    ifelse (d >= WS | d < SE, "Winter",
      ifelse (d >= SE & d < SS, "Spring",
        ifelse (d >= SS & d < FE, "Summer", "Fall")))
}

my.dates <- as.Date("2011-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 0:60
head(getSeason(my.dates), 24)
#  [1] "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"  
#  [8] "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"   "Fall"  
# [15] "Winter" "Winter" "Winter" "Winter" "Winter" "Winter"
```

**One note:** 2012 is a good year to which to convert all of the dates; since it is a leap year, any February 29ths in your data set will be handled smoothly.

Comment: Very handy function, I hope it finds its way into a package.

Comment: There is an "|" where there should be a "&" in the first ifelse loop.  I can't edit it as it is too short to edit apparently.  but love the code: Thank you!

Comment: @Puddlebunk No, it is meant to be an "|", as there are two disjunct ways to be in winter -- the calendar date can be after the winter solstice OR before the spring equinox. Glad you've found the code helpful.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien.  I see that now.  I was using your code (thanks again) to set up a fall and a spring burn window so I didn't have the issue of one category falling on different sides of the calendar:  hence my confusion.

Comment: @Puddlebunk Cool. Once upon a time, I worked in natural resources at Indiana Dunes National Lakeshore and helped manage controlled burns in Karner Blue butterfly habitat. Great memories of that.

Comment: What is the `+ 0:60` doing ? I see that the final length of the object is 61, but how to interpret the `+0:60`? Adding an integer `+10` would add 10 days to the date.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil It just gives you a length 61 sequence of dates, starting on December 1st, which I'm using there as some example data.

Comment: Note that this uses the 15th for the equinox and solstices, but that is not how it is commonly defined: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_solstice

Answer (score 12):

I have something similarly ugly as Tim:

```
R> toSeason <- function(dat) {
+ 
+     stopifnot(class(dat) == "Date")
+ 
+     scalarCheck <- function(dat) {
+         m <- as.POSIXlt(dat)$mon + 1        # correct for 0:11 range
+         d <- as.POSIXlt(dat)$mday           # correct for 0:11 range
+         if ((m == 3 & d >= 21) | (m == 4) | (m == 5) | (m == 6 & d < 21)) {
+             r <- 1
+         } else if ((m == 6 & d >= 21) | (m == 7) | (m == 8) | (m == 9 & d < 21)) {
+             r <- 2
+         } else if ((m == 9 & d >= 21) | (m == 10) | (m == 11) | (m == 12 & d < 21)) {
+             r <- 3
+         } else {
+             r <- 4
+         }
+         r
+     }
+ 
+     res <- sapply(dat, scalarCheck)
+     res <- ordered(res, labels=c("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"))
+     invisible(res)
+ }
R>
```

And here is a test:

```
R> date <- Sys.Date() + (0:11)*30
R> DF <- data.frame(Date=date, Season=toSeason(date))
R> DF
         Date Season
1  2012-02-29 Winter
2  2012-03-30 Spring
3  2012-04-29 Spring
4  2012-05-29 Spring
5  2012-06-28 Summer
6  2012-07-28 Summer
7  2012-08-27 Summer
8  2012-09-26   Fall
9  2012-10-26   Fall
10 2012-11-25   Fall
11 2012-12-25 Winter
12 2013-01-24 Winter
R> summary(DF)
      Date               Season 
 Min.   :2012-02-29   Spring:3  
 1st Qu.:2012-05-21   Summer:3  
 Median :2012-08-12   Fall  :3  
 Mean   :2012-08-12   Winter:3  
 3rd Qu.:2012-11-02             
 Max.   :2013-01-24             
R>
```

Answer (score 7):

I would create a lookup table, and go from there. An example (note the code obfuscation using the `d()` function and the pragmatic way of filling the lut):

```
# Making lookup table (lut), only needed once. You can save
# it using save() for later use. Note I take a leap year.
d = function(month_day) which(lut$month_day == month_day)
lut = data.frame(all_dates = as.POSIXct("2012-1-1") + ((0:365) * 3600 * 24),
                 season = NA)
lut = within(lut, { month_day = strftime(all_dates, "%b-%d") })
lut[c(d("Jan-01"):d("Mar-20"), d("Dec-21"):d("Dec-31")), "season"] = "winter"
lut[c(d("Mar-21"):d("Jun-20")), "season"] = "spring"
lut[c(d("Jun-21"):d("Sep-20")), "season"] = "summer"
lut[c(d("Sep-21"):d("Dec-20")), "season"] = "autumn"
rownames(lut) = lut$month_day
```

After creating the lookup table, you can extract quite easily from it to what season a month/day combination belongs to:

```
dat = data.frame(dates = Sys.Date() + (0:11)*30)
dat = within(dat, { 
  season =  lut[strftime(dates, "%b-%d"), "season"] 
 })
> dat
        dates season
1  2012-02-29 winter
2  2012-03-30 spring
3  2012-04-29 spring
4  2012-05-29 spring
5  2012-06-28 summer
6  2012-07-28 summer
7  2012-08-27 summer
8  2012-09-26 autumn
9  2012-10-26 autumn
10 2012-11-25 autumn
11 2012-12-25 winter
12 2013-01-24 winter
```

All nice and vectorized :). I think once the table is created, this is very quick.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use time2season function. It gets date and generates season:

```
time2season(x, out.fmt = "months", type="default")
```

You can find more infromation [here](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/hydroTSM/time2season.html).

Comment: the here link didn't work for me, so im adding a working link: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hydroTSM/versions/0.6-0/topics/time2season

Answer (score 4):

I think this would do it, but it's an ugly solution:

```
    my.dates <- as.Date("2011-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 0:60
    ld <- as.Date("12-15", format = "%m-%d")
    hd <- as.Date("01-15", format = "%m-%d")
    my.dates2 <- as.Date(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(my.dates),split=""),function(x)   paste(x[6:10],collapse=""))),format="%m-%d")
    my.dates[my.dates2 <= hd | my.dates2 >= ld] 
    [1] "2011-12-15" "2011-12-16" "2011-12-17" "2011-12-18" "2011-12-19"
    [6] "2011-12-20" "2011-12-21" "2011-12-22" "2011-12-23" "2011-12-24"
    [11] "2011-12-25" "2011-12-26" "2011-12-27" "2011-12-28" "2011-12-29"
    [16] "2011-12-30" "2011-12-31" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03"
    [21] "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08"
    [26] "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10" "2012-01-11" "2012-01-12" "2012-01-13"
    [31] "2012-01-14" "2012-01-15"
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not fast but is flexible about the starts of the seasons as long as they are defined in a dataframe first for the function `assignSeason`. It requires magrittr for the piping functions, lubridate for the `year` function, and dplyr for `mutate`.

```
seasons <- data.frame(
   SE = as.POSIXct(c("2009-3-20", "2010-3-20", "2011-3-20", "2012-3-20", 
        "2013-3-20", "2014-3-20"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
   SS = as.POSIXct(c("2009-6-21", "2010-6-21", "2011-6-21", "2012-6-20",
        "2013-6-21", "2014-6-21"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
   FE = as.POSIXct(c("2009-9-22", "2010-9-23", "2011-9-23", "2012-9-22",
        "2013-9-22", "2014-9-23"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
   WS = as.POSIXct(c("2009-12-21", "2010-12-21", "2011-12-22", "2012-12-21", 
        "2013-12-21", "2014-12-21"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
)

assignSeason <- function(dat, SeasonStarts=seasons) {
    dat %<>% mutate(
        Season = lapply(Date,
            function(x) {
                findInterval(
                    x, 
                    SeasonStarts[which(year(x)==year(SeasonStarts$WS)), ]
                )
            }
        ) %>% unlist    
    )
    dat[which(dat$Season==0 | dat$Season==4), ]$Season   <- "Winter"
    dat[which(dat$Season==1), ]$Season                  <- "Spring"
    dat[which(dat$Season==2), ]$Season                  <- "Summer"
    dat[which(dat$Season==3), ]$Season                  <- "Fall"
    return(dat)
}
```

Example data:

```
dat = data.frame(
    Date = as.POSIXct(strptime(as.Date("2011-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 
        (0:10)*30, format="%Y-%m-%d"))
)
dat %>% assignSeason
```

Result:

```
         Date Season
1  2011-12-01   Fall
2  2011-12-31 Winter
3  2012-01-30 Winter
4  2012-02-29 Winter
5  2012-03-30 Spring
6  2012-04-29 Spring
7  2012-05-29 Spring
8  2012-06-28 Summer
9  2012-07-28 Summer
10 2012-08-27 Summer
11 2012-09-26   Fall
```

Answer (score 2):

I think library zoo would be easy

```
   library(zoo)
      yq <- as.yearqtr(as.yearmon(DF$dates, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1/12)
      DF$Season <- factor(format(yq, "%q"), levels = 1:4, 
      labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a more general solution, that nevertheless needs 3 libraries... It considers all years and the hemisphere:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

get.seasons <- function(dates, hemisphere = "N"){
  years <- unique(year(dates))
  years <- c(min(years - 1), max(years + 1), years) %>% sort

  if(hemisphere == "N"){
    seasons <- c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall")}else{
      seasons <- c("summer", "fall", "winter", "spring")}

  dt.dates <- bind_rows(
    data.table(date = as.Date(paste0(years, "-12-21")), init = seasons[1], type = "B"),# Summer in south hemisphere
    data.table(date = as.Date(paste0(years, "-3-21")), init = seasons[2], type = "B"), # Fall in south hemisphere
    data.table(date = as.Date(paste0(years, "-6-21")), init = seasons[3], type = "B"), # Winter in south hemisphere
    data.table(date = as.Date(paste0(years, "-9-23")), init = seasons[4], type = "B"), # Winter in south hemisphere
    data.table(date = dates, i = 1:(length(dates)), type = "A") # dates to compute
  )[order(date)] 

  dt.dates[, init := zoo::na.locf(init)] 

  return(dt.dates[type == "A"][order(i)]$init)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

8 years later and there is a really easy Lubridate answer for checking if X date is in Y date range.

```
as.Date("2020-05-01") %within% (as.Date("2020-01-01") %--% as.Date("2021-01-01"))
```

So you'd define your date ranges using the lubridate date range opperator, %--%

```
range_1 <- A_Date %--% Z_date
```

then to check if X date is within range_1 use %within%

```
library(lubridate)
    summer <-
      ymd(paste0(seq(2019, 2021), "-01", "-01")) %--% ymd(paste0(seq(2019, 2021), "-05", "-05"))
    ymd("2020-02-01") %within% summer
```

since the above ranges are from 20xx-01-1 %--% 20xx-05-05 the query above returns FALSE, TRUE, FALSE but you could set a query to return TRUE if any are TRUE.

Comment: Yes, but what if the season you want to check goes through newyear? You wildly underestimate the difficulty of this issue. My solution was to split up the season that intersects newyear, remap all season boundaries to the year 2000 and than you can perform the simple fewer-than/bigger-than check

Comment: It would be interesting to see when lubridate got this feature. When we were solving this problem years ago, I don't think any of the cool kids used lubridate to any significant extent.

Comment: @Pieterjan I think you're actually over complicating it. Go ahead and try out the code and you'll see it's really not difficult.

# CODE STARTS HERE #

party_week <- 
  c(
    #date range 1
    as.Date("2020-09-01") %--% as.Date("2020-09-08"), 
    #date range 2
    as.Date("2020-11-01") %--% as.Date("2021-01-13"),
    #date range 3
    as.Date("2021-09-01") %--% as.Date("2021-09-08")
  )


as.Date("2020-09-03") %within% party_week
any(as.Date("2021-01-03") %within% party_week)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes Lubridate did not have this option back in 2012 lol.

Comment: Ok but now you yourself know when you have to use 2021 instead of 2020 in order to easily compare. Now you have to adapt your code for any year. But when will you use dateToCheck.year+1 (2021) instead of dateToCheck.year (2020)? Tough riddle? Splitting the winter is easier though

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate approach to this issue is by splitting up the season that intersects newyear.

Now I'm a c# guy but the idea behind the season check is the same for all languages.
I've created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pieterjandc/L3prwqmh/1/

Here is the core code, which splits up the season crossing the newyear, and performs the comparision:

```
const seasons = [{
    name: 'Spring',
    start: new Date(2000, 2, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 5, 20)
},{
    name: 'Summer',
    start: new Date(2000, 5, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 8, 20)
},{
    name: 'Autumn/Fall',
    start: new Date(2000, 8, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 11, 20)
},{
    name: 'Winter',
    start: new Date(2000, 11, 21),
    end: new Date(2001, 2, 20)
}];

/** Checks if a date is within a specified season */
function checkSeason(season, date) {
    let remappedStart = new Date(2000, season.start.getMonth(), season.start.getDate());
    let remappedDate = new Date(2000, date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    let remappedEnd = new Date(2000, season.end.getMonth(), season.end.getDate());
    
    // Check if the season crosses newyear
    if (season.start.getFullYear() === season.end.getFullYear()) {
        // Simple comparison
        return (remappedStart <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= remappedEnd);
    } else {
        // Split the season, remap all to year 2000, and perform a simple comparison
        return (remappedStart <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= new Date(2000, 11, 31))
        || (new Date(2000, 0, 1) <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= remappedEnd);
    }
}

function findSeason(seasons, date) {
    for (let i = 0; i < seasons.length; i++) {
        let isInSeason = checkSeason(seasons[i], date);
        if (isInSeason === true) {
            return seasons[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but an additional base R solution (I stole @Josh O'Brien's brilliant logic for the astronomical seasons piece) updating the UTC dates for equinoxes and solstices for the 2016 - 2026 decade (i will endeavour to add a lookup table for the UTC dates for the equinoxes and solstices in the past and future).

```
# Function to take a date vector and return the season
# season_stamper => function
season_stamper <- function(
  date_vec, 
  date_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d", 
  hemisphere = c("north", "south"),
  season_type = c(
    ifelse(hemisphere == "south", 
           "monthly periods", "astronomical"),
           ifelse(hemisphere == "south", 
            "astronomical", "monthly periods")
  )){
  # Resolve which hemisphere was selected: 
  # hemisphere_selected => string scalar
  hemisphere_selected <- match.arg(hemisphere)
  # Extract the month number from the dates: 
  # mon_nos => integer vector
  mon_nos <- (as.POSIXlt(strptime(date_vec, date_fmt))$mon + 1)
  # Resolve the type of season: season_type_selected => character scalar
  season_type_selected <- match.arg(season_type)
  # If the season type is a 3-month period: 
  if(season_type_selected == "monthly periods"){
    # Resolve the seasons based on the hemisphere:
    # seasons => string vector
    seasons <- switch(
      hemisphere_selected,
      "north"=c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"),
      c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring")
    )
    # Stamp the date vector: season_stamps => string vector
    season_stamps <- seasons[((mon_nos %/% (12 / 4)) %% 4 + 1)]
  # Otherwise: 
  }else{
    # Convert dates from any year to 2020: d=> Date Scalar
    d <- as.Date(strftime(date_vec, format="2020-%m-%d"))
    
    # If the dates are from the northern hemisphere:
    if(hemisphere_selected == "north"){
      # Store as a variable Date of the Winter Solstice for a leap year: 
      # WS => date scalar 
      WS <- as.Date("2020-12-21", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable Date of the Spring Equinox for a leap year: 
      # SE => date scalar 
      SE <- as.Date("2020-3-20",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable Date of the Summer Solstice for a leap year: 
      # SS => date scalar 
      SS <- as.Date("2020-6-21",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable Date of the Fall Equinox for a leap year: 
      # SS => date scalar 
      FE <- as.Date("2020-9-22",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Resolve the season: season_stamps => character vector
      season_stamps <- ifelse(d >= WS | d < SE, "Winter",
              ifelse(d >= SE & d < SS, "Spring",
                      ifelse(d >= SS & d < FE, "Summer", "Fall")))
    # Otherwise: 
    }else{
      # Store as a variable Date of the Summer Solstice for a leap year: 
      # WS => date scalar 
      SS <- as.Date("2020-12-21", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable the Date of the Autumn Equinox:
      # AE => date scalar
      AE <- as.Date("2020-3-20",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable the Date of the Winter Solstice: 
      # WS => date scalar
      WS <- as.Date("2020-6-21",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Store as a variable the DAte of the Spring Equinox: 
      # SE => date scalar
      SE <- as.Date("2020-9-22",  format = "%Y-%m-%d")
      # Resolve the season: season_stamps => character vector
      season_stamps <- ifelse(d >= SS | d < AE, "Summer", 
             ifelse(d >= SE & d < SS, "Spring",
                    ifelse(d >= WS & d < SE, "Winter", "Autumn")))
    }
  }
  # Explicitly define the returned object: 
  # string vecctor => Global Env
  return(season_stamps)
}

# Data: 
my.dates <- as.Date("2019-12-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") + 0:60
low.date <- as.Date("2019-12-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
high.date <- as.Date("2020-01-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

date_vec <- my.dates[my.dates <= high.date & my.dates >= low.date]
```