# Fill specific values in a data frame using another column as an index

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, intervals

I have a data frame that looks like this:

> ```
> species<-"ABC"
> ind<-rep(1:4,each=24)
> hour<-rep(seq(0,23,by=1),4)
> month<-rep(seq(1,12),8)
> depth<-runif(length(ind),1,50)
> df<-data.frame(species,ind,month,hour,depth)
> ```

What I would like is to use the column month to specify intervals for each season and return those values in a new column from the same data frame. I was using this code for the seasons, which seems to work fine,

> ```
> # Classify months into seasons
>
> summer<-c(1,2,12)
> fall<-c(3,4,5)
> winter<-c(6,7,8)
> spring<-c(9,10,11)
>
> # Create a new column with seasons
>
> df$season<-NA
> for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
>   if(df$month[i]%in%summer){df$season[i]<-"1-summer"} else
>     if(df$month[i]%in%fall){df$season[i]<-"2-fall"} else
>       if(df$month[i]%in%winter){df$season[i]<-"3-winter"} else
>         if(df$month[i]%in%spring){df$season[i]<-"spring"}
> ```
>
> }

However, this loop in already inside of a bigger loop with more complex and bigger data bases. So I was looking for a faster, more efficient approach. The reason that I am using a loop rather than cutting or subsetting my original data frame is because the first loop that I am using is separating and performing analyses on individual animals. The length of resulting data frame varies between animals and one of the problems that I was having is that not all animals were present in all months, so when I was trying to assign seasons inside the loop for animals that were not present on a particular season, then R gave me an error message...

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500114/find-which-season-a-particular-date-belongs-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just generate the lookup table for season names and apply that:

```
> season.names <- rep("",12)
> season.names[summer] <- "1-summer"
> season.names[fall] <- "2-fall"
> season.names[winter] <- "3-winter"
> season.names[spring] <- "4-spring"
> season.names
 [1] "1-summer" "1-summer" "2-fall"   "2-fall"   "2-fall"   "3-winter" "3-winter"
 [8] "3-winter" "4-spring" "4-spring" "4-spring" "1-summer"
> df$season <- season.names[df$month]
> head(df)
  species ind month hour     depth   season
1     ABC   1     1    0 41.643471 1-summer
2     ABC   1     2    1 36.055533 1-summer
3     ABC   1     3    2  1.901639   2-fall
4     ABC   1     4    3  7.737539   2-fall
5     ABC   1     5    4 35.327364   2-fall
6     ABC   1     6    5  9.156978 3-winter
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same approach for "day"/"night" but I noticed that the last "night" for hour 23 is not showing so that code does not run properly. Any suggestions?                               day<-seq(6,17,1)
alltimes<-seq(0,23,1)
night<-alltimes[!alltimes%in%day]

diel.names<-rep("",24)
diel.names[day]<-"day"
diel.names[night]<-"night"
diel.names

Comment: The problem is that the hours start at 0 and go to 23, but the vector diel.names has to be indexed from 1 to 24.  One way to deal with that is just to have index `i` refer to hour `i-1`: `diel.names[day+1]<-"day" ; diel.names[night+1]<-"night"; df$diel <- diel.names[df$hour+1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
seasons <- c("1-summer", "2-fall", "3-winter", "spring")
df$season2 <- factor(trunc(df$month %% 12 / 3) + 1, labels = seasons)
table(df$season, df$season2)
```

You can convert `df$season2` to `character` if you wish.

Comment: It does not work. It gives me this error message "Error in factor(trunc(df$month%%12/3) + 1, labels = seasons) : 
  invalid labels; length 4 should be 1 or 0"

Comment: @user1626688 You receive this error because you did not include `month` in your data frame `df`. Both djhurio's solution and your loop will work if you add the column `month` to your data frame.

Comment: I am trying to run this code in my real script but it is giving me a similar error message "invalid labels; length 4 should be 1 or 1". In some of the individuals there is only data for October and November. Is this going to be an issue here with this code?

Comment: Strange, I don't receive the error on example data. Try to simplify if something doesn't work. Drop `factor`. Does this work? `df$season2 <- trunc(df$month %% 12 / 3) + 1`

Comment: The example is fine. This code seems to work fine, but when I try to run the code on real data  (which not always have all months because some of the animals in my study were only present for 3 or 4 months) then I get an error message. I am not sure if I need to have all months so that the code can specify all seasons. If for example the months for summer are missing, then I don't know if it will still work?

Comment: You don't  need all month represented in data for code to work. Did you tried the version without factor `trunc(df$month %% 12 / 3) + 1`? Does it produce another error? What is the output of `table(df$month)` from your data?