# Assigning Dates to Fiscal Year

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm trying to come up with some code that will look at a date and then assign it to a fiscal year. I'm totally stuck.

I have a variable that contains dates in POSIXct format:

```
df$Date
#2015-05-01 CST
#2015-04-30 CST
#2014-09-01 CST
```

What I need to be able to do is take those dates and return a fiscal year, which runs from May 1 - April 30. For example, Fiscal Year 2016 runs 2015-05-01 through 2016-04-30. Results would look something like this:

```
df$Date                df$FiscalYear
#2015-05-01 CST        #FY2016
#2015-04-30 CST        #FY2015
#2014-09-01 CST        #FY2015
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684514/how-to-calculate-mean-by-date-grouped-as-fiscal-quarters

Comment: I don't find that solution to be particularly clear - Or I'm not smart enough to understand it. Probably the latter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  They all return numeric years but if you really need a string starting with FY then use `paste0("FY", ...)`, e.g. `paste0("FY", as.integer(as.yearmon(dates) - 4/12 + 1))` .  They all support vector input, i.e. the input `dates` can be a vector.

**1) zoo::as.yearmon** The zoo package has a `"yearmon"` class which represents year/months as year + fraction where fraction = 0 for jan, 1/12 for feb, 2/12 for march and so on.

Using that this one-liner will do it.  It subtracts 4/12 (since April is end of year) and adds 1 (i.e. add one year).  Then to get the year take the integer part:

```
library(zoo)

as.integer(as.yearmon(dates) - 4/12 + 1)
## [1] 2016 2015 2015
```

**2) POSIXlt** Here is a solution that does not use any packages.  Convert the dates to POSIXlt class.  Its `mo` component represents Jan as 0, Feb as 1, etc. so if we are May or later (`mo` is 4 or more) then the fiscal year is the following calendar year otherwise it is the current calendar year.  The `year` component of POSIXlt objects is the number of years since 1900 so add the year to 1900 plus 1 if we are at May or later:

```
lt <- as.POSIXlt(dates)
lt$year + (lt$mo >= 4) + 1900
## [1] 2016 2015 2015
```

**3) format** Add the year to 1 if the month is greater than or equal to 5 (or to zero if not).  This also uses no packages:

```
as.numeric(format(dates, "%Y")) + (format(dates, "%m") >= "05")
## [1] 2016 2015 2015
```

**4) substr**.  We can extract the year using `substr`, convert to numeric and add 1 if the extracted month (also extracted using`substr`) is "05" or greater.;  Again no packages are used.

```
as.numeric(substr(dates, 1, 4)) + (substr(dates, 6, 7) >= "05")
## [1] 2016 2015 2015
```

**5) read.table**  This also uses no packages.

```
with(read.table(text = format(dates), sep = "-"), V1 + (V2 >= 5))
## [1] 2016 2015 2015
```

**Note:** We used this as the input `dates`:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-05-01", "2015-04-30", "2014-09-01"))
```

Comment: added (2), (3) and (4)

Comment: Thanks GG. The UK equivalent is I think `as.numeric(format(dates, "%Y")) - (format(dates, "%m") <= "03")`

Comment: Awesome, went with 3, good work.  Should be the answer, more readable.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to G. Grothendieck's nice response.  With `lubridate`:

```
year(dates) + (month(dates) >= 5)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `seq` with POSIXct objects to generate a list of the "cutpoints" or 1st day of the fiscal year for the years spanning your data, then use `findInterval` to compute which of the intervals a particular date falls into:

```
> dates <- as.POSIXct( c('2015-05-01','2015-04-30','2014-09-01'))
> fy.tmp <- seq( as.POSIXct('2000-05-01'), length=25, by='year')
> fiscalYear <- (2001:2025)[ findInterval(dates,fy.tmp) ]
> fiscalYear
[1] 2016 2015 2015
```

You could also use the `cut` function instead of `findInterval` if you want a factor as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying this:

```
Federal.FY <- function(x,firstMonth=10,  # I've altered this line to follow the federal fiscal year, October
                       fy.prefix='FY',
                       quarter.prefix='Q',
                       sep='-',
                       level.range=c(min(x), max(x)) ) {if(level.range[1] > min(x) | level.range[2] < max(x)) {
warning(paste0('The range of x is greater than level.range. Values ',
               'outside level.range will be returned as NA.'))}
quarterString <- function(d) {
year <- as.integer(format(d, format='%Y'))
month <- as.integer(format(d, format='%m'))
y <- ifelse(firstMonth > 1 & month >= firstMonth, year+1, year)
q <- cut( (month - firstMonth) %% 12, breaks=c(-Inf,2,5,8,Inf),
          labels=paste0(quarter.prefix, 1:4))
return(paste0(fy.prefix, y, sep, q))}
vals <- quarterString(x)
levels <- unique(quarterString(seq(
as.Date(format(level.range[1], '%Y-%m-01')),
as.Date(format(level.range[2], '%Y-%m-28')), by='month')))
return(factor(vals, levels=levels, ordered=TRUE))}

d <- as.Date("2016-10-02")
Federal.FY(d)
##[1] FY2017-Q1
##Levels: FY2017-Q1
```