# If in date range then assign value

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a bunch of University data with dates.  I want to create a variable in my dataframe which codes by semester ("Fall","Spring","Summer") by looking at date ranges, which differ each year, so I want to code a series of if then statements (by referring to historical University calendars).  I am struggling a bit as to how to do this.  I envision it would look somethign like this:

```
if( ( (mydata$date>="2009-08-24") and (mydata$date<="2009-12-18") ) == TRUE),
   mydata$semester <- "Fall"
```

I have a long series of such statements

in short:  if (condition and condition) = true, then apply value

### Seems so simple!

After it became clear I didn't explain myself well enough I have (later same day I posted this question), below, created sample data:

```
# Assemble Data  (real dataset is much larger, 70,000 records)
Score<-c(23,2,15,2,12,44,2,NA,34,64,2,34,32,54,NA,17,37,33,32,4,13,19,23,34,86)  
Date<-c('2012-08-27','2012-09-03','2012-09-04','2012-09-28','2012-10-19','2012-10-19','2012-10-19','2012-11-06','2012-11-20','2012-12-13','2013-01-16','2013-01-30','2013-01-30','2013-01-30','2013-02-07','2013-02-14','2013-02-21','2013-02-22','2013-03-03','2013-03-04','2013-03-20','2013-04-02','2013-04-11','2013-04-27','2013-05-04')

#create data frame
university<-data.frame(Date,Score)

# code below doesn't work, because once I have correct value for unversity$Semester I don't want to replace it with "NA" or "Not Fall"
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-08-27' & university$Date <= '2012-09-02', university$Semester<-"Fall", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-09-03' & university$Date <= '2012-09-03', university$Semester<-"Labor Day", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-09-04' & university$Date <= '2012-11-16', university$Semester<-"Fall", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-11-17' & university$Date <= '2012-11-25', university$Semester<-"Fall Break", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-11-26' & university$Date <= '2012-12-13', university$Semester<-"Fall", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-12-14' & university$Date <= '2012-12-20', university$Semester<-"Fall Finals", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2012-12-21' & university$Date <= '2013-01-13', university$Semester<-"Winter Break", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-01-14' & university$Date <= '2013-01-20', university$Semester<-"Spring", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-01-21' & university$Date <= '2013-01-21', university$Semester<-"MLK Day", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-01-22' & university$Date <= '2013-03-15', university$Semester<-"Spring", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-03-16' & university$Date <= '2013-03-24', university$Semester<-"Spring Break", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-03-25' & university$Date <= '2013-05-02', university$Semester<-"Spring", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
ifelse(university$Date >= '2013-05-03' & university$Date <= '2013-05-10', university$Semester<-"Spring Finals", do-not-overwirte-correct-assignment-so-do-nothing)
```

If the above ifelse statements worked, the data frame university would look like this:

Date    Score   Semester
2012-08-27  23  Fall
2012-09-03  2   Labor Day
2012-09-04  15  Fall
2012-09-28  2   Fall
2012-10-19  12  Fall
2012-10-19  44  Fall
2012-10-19  2   Fall
2012-11-06  NA  Fall
2012-11-20  34  Fall Break
2012-12-13  64  Fall
2013-01-16  2   Spring
2013-01-30  34  Spring
2013-01-30  32  Spring
2013-01-30  54  Spring
2013-02-07  NA  Spring
2013-02-14  17  Spring
2013-02-21  37  Spring
2013-02-22  33  Spring
2013-03-03  32  Spring
2013-03-04  4   Spring
2013-03-20  13  Spring Break
2013-04-02  19  Spring
2013-04-11  23  Spring
2013-04-27  34  Spring
2013-05-04  86  Spring Finals

Comment: This isn't a good scalable answer, but it solves your immediate need.  Using an `ifelse` statement and the `&` operator. `ifelse(dates$V1 >= '2009-08-24' & dates$V1 <= '2009-12-18', "Fall", 'Not Fall')`

Comment: To scale this, would you maybe just want to categorize the months?  `ifelse(month(mydata$date) < 6, "Spring", ifelse(month(mydata$date) < 8, "Summer"), "Fall")`  This would only work if semester months are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I would think the `cut.Date()` function would be useful here, but you really didn't provide a good [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to test it on. It's unclear how you are storing your date breaks of even if you've properly converted your date values to proper Date objects in R.

Comment: I do not think this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045753/how-to-classify-a-given-date-time-by-the-season-e-g-summer-autumn     I will try to create a reproduce able example

Comment: I've added code at the bottom of the original question.  I feel like the direction maloneypatr was going with the ifelse statement was coming closest to what I need.

Comment: My question is not the same as the one about seasons - their lookup table has all the possible dates/times that they want to tag.  My "lookup table" (or, the way I have it, a series of ifelse statements) only has first and last date for each range.  They are matching things up, I am spanning a range.  Instructions say I should explain why my Q is not the same as one that it is marked as a duplicate of, this is me doing that!

Comment: @SteveT , you need to do a nested `ifelse` statement.  Instead of writing `do-not-overwrite...`, input the next ifelse statement.  It'll be long and tedious, but that's what you're looking for.  In addition, you need to convert `Date` to a Date object.  `university$Date <- as.Date(university$Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')`