# trouble debugging my ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting expected results with an `ifelse` statement, used to parse University data into semesters and breaks within/between semester, creating a new column in the data frame, `refstats$Semester`.

Here's some sample data and my code for the section where I think/hope the problem is:

```
Date<-c('2009-04-12','2009-07-07','2009-08-09','2009-08-20','2009-08-25','2009-08-30','2020-09-03','2009-09-07','2009-11-15','2009-11-22','2009-12-05','2009-12-12','2010-01-02','2010-01-18','2010-02-14','2010-03-22','2010-05-23','2010-06-13','2010-06-19','2010-08-08','2010-09-05','2010-12-09','2011-03-27','2011-08-06','2011-12-09','2012-06-10','2013-01-20','2013-01-21','2013-05-10','2013-08-03','2013-12-14','2014-05-22','2015-03-20','2015-08-20','2015-11-30','2015-12-15','2016-01-10','2016-02-15')

# create data frame
refstats<-data.frame(Date)

# convert Date to a Date object for evaluation in nested    ifelse statement
refstats$Date <- as.Date(refstats$Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

# ---- determine Semester, broken up into school year ifelse statments
#  because R gets confused if the ifelse is too deeply nested.

# dummvar is just something to do in the final else condition, so it doesn't
# overwrite the correct Semester once it is found.

# 2009-2010
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-08-24") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-09-06"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-09-07") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-09-07"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-09-08") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-11-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-11-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-11-29"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-11-30") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-12-10"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-12-11") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2009-12-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2009-12-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-01-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-01-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-03-19"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-03-20") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-03-28"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-03-29") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-05-06"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-05-07") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-05-14"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-05-15") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-05-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-05-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-06-12"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-06-13") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-06-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-06-14") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-08-07"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-08-08") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-08-22"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2010-2011
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-08-23") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-09-05"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-09-06") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-09-06"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-09-07") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-11-19"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-11-20") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-11-28"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-11-29") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-12-09"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-12-10") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2010-12-17"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2010-12-18") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-01-17"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-01-18") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-03-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-03-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-03-27"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-03-28") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-05-05"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-05-06") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-05-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-05-14") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-05-15"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-05-16") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-06-11"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-06-12") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-06-12"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-06-13") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-08-06"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-08-07") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-08-21"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2011-2012
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-08-22") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-09-04"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-09-05") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-09-05"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-09-06") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-11-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-11-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-11-27"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-11-28") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-12-08"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-12-09") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2011-12-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2011-12-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-01-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-01-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-03-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-03-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-03-25"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-03-26") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-05-03"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-05-04") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-05-11"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-05-12") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-05-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-05-15") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-06-09"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-06-10") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-06-10"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-06-11") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-08-04"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-08-05") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-08-26"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2012-2013 note this year has MLK day within Spring Semester
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-08-27") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-09-02"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-09-03") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-09-03"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-09-04") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-11-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-11-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-11-25"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-11-26") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-12-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-12-14") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2012-12-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2012-12-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-01-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-01-14") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-01-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-01-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-01-21"), refstats$Semester<-"MLK Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-01-22") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-03-15"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-03-16") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-03-24"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-03-25") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-05-02"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-05-03") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-05-10"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-05-11") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-05-12"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-05-13") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-06-08"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-06-09") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-06-09"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-06-10") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-08-03"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-08-04") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-08-25"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2013-2014
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-08-26") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-09-01"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-09-02") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-09-02"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-09-03") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-11-22"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-11-23") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-12-01"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-12-02") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-12-12"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-12-13") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2013-12-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2013-12-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-01-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-01-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-03-21"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-03-22") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-03-30"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-03-31") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-05-08"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-05-09") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-05-16"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-05-17") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-05-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-05-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-06-14"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-06-15") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-06-15"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-06-16") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-08-09"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-08-10") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-08-24"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2014-2015
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-08-25") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-08-31"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-09-01") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-09-01"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-09-02") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-11-21"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-11-22") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-11-30"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-12-01") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-12-11"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-12-12") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2014-12-19"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2014-12-20") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-01-19"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-01-20") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-03-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-03-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-03-29"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-03-30") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-05-07"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring", 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-05-08") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-05-15"), refstats$Semester<-"Spring Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-05-16") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-05-17"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-05-18") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-06-13"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer I" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-06-14") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-06-14"), refstats$Semester<-"Closed" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-06-15") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-08-08"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer II" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-08-09") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-08-23"), refstats$Semester<-"Summer Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )

# 2015-
ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-08-24") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-09-06"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-09-07") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-09-07"), refstats$Semester<-"Labor Day" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-09-08") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-11-20"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-11-21") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-11-29"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Break" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-11-30") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-12-10"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-12-11") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2015-12-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Fall Finals" , 
  ifelse(refstats$Date >= as.Date("2015-12-19") & refstats$Date <= as.Date("2016-01-18"), refstats$Semester<-"Winter Break" , 
  dummvar<-NA ) ) ) ) ) ) )

refstats
```

I would have expected the final statement to print something that looks like:

> Date   Semester
>   2009-04-12  NA
>   2009-07-07  NA
>   2009-08-09  NA
>   2009-08-20  NA
>   2009-08-25  Fall
>   2009-08-30  Fall
>   2020-09-03  NA
>   2009-09-07  Labor Day
>   2009-11-15  Fall
>   2009-11-22  Fall Break
>   2009-12-05  Fall
>   2009-12-12  Fall Finals
>   2010-01-02  Winter Break
>   2010-01-18  Winter Break
>   2010-02-14  Spring
>   2010-03-22  Spring Break
>   2010-05-23  Summer I
>   2010-06-13  Closed
>   2010-06-19  Summer II
>   2010-08-08  Summer Break
>   2010-09-05  Fall
>   2010-12-09  Fall
>   2011-03-27  Spring Break
>   2011-08-06  Summer II
>   2011-12-09  Fall Break
>   2012-06-10  Summer I
>   2013-01-20  Spring
>   2013-01-21  MLK Day
>   2013-05-10  Spring Finals
>   2013-08-03  Summer II
>   2013-12-14  Fall Finals
>   2014-05-22  Summer I
>   2015-03-20  Spring
>   2015-08-20  Summer Break
>   2015-11-30  Fall
>   2015-12-15  Fall Finals
>   2016-01-10  Winter Break
>   2016-02-15  NA

Instead, the `refstats$Semeseter` is all "Winter Break"

Any thoughts or advice on how I might have gone astray, or perhaps some better approach to the problem?  My last question was related to this - I'm still struggling to understand.

---

deleted some of intermediate attempts to resolve question, so that I stay in the 30,000 characther limit

---

Third try, adding as.Date:

I had to replace my initial code (due to 30,0000 character limit on asking question) - so the new code is at the top, with as.Date in there.

Alas!  Now I'm back to everything coming out as "Winter Break" again!!!

---

Fourth try, trying to use `findInterval`:

```
Date<-c('2009-04-12','2009-07-07','2009-08-09','2009-08-20','2009-08-25','2009-08-30','2020-09-03','2009-09-07','2009-11-15','2009-11-22','2009-12-05','2009-12-12','2010-01-02','2010-01-18','2010-02-14','2010-03-22','2010-05-23','2010-06-13','2010-06-19','2010-08-08','2010-09-05','2010-12-09','2011-03-27','2011-08-06','2011-12-09','2012-06-10','2013-01-20','2013-01-21','2013-05-10','2013-08-03','2013-12-14','2014-05-22','2015-03-20','2015-08-20','2015-11-30','2015-12-15','2016-01-10','2016-02-15')

Semester<-c('NA','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','MLK Day','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','Spring','Spring Break','Spring','Spring Finals','Closed','Summer I','Closed','Summer II','Summer Break','Fall','Labor Day','Fall','Fall Break','Fall','Fall Finals','Winter Break','NA')
StartDate<-c('1000-01-01','2009-08-24','2009-09-07','2009-09-08','2009-11-21','2009-11-30','2009-12-11','2009-12-19','2010-01-19','2010-03-20','2010-03-29','2010-05-07','2010-05-15','2010-05-17','2010-06-13','2010-06-14','2010-08-08','2010-08-23','2010-09-06','2010-09-07','2010-11-20','2010-11-29','2010-12-10','2010-12-18','2011-01-18','2011-03-19','2011-03-28','2011-05-06','2011-05-14','2011-05-16','2011-06-12','2011-06-13','2011-08-07','2011-08-22','2011-09-05','2011-09-06','2011-11-19','2011-11-28','2011-12-09','2011-12-17','2012-01-17','2012-03-17','2012-03-26','2012-05-04','2012-05-12','2012-05-15','2012-06-10','2012-06-11','2012-08-05','2012-08-27','2012-09-03','2012-09-04','2012-11-17','2012-11-26','2012-12-14','2012-12-21','2013-01-14','2013-01-21','2013-01-22','2013-03-16','2013-03-25','2013-05-03','2013-05-11','2013-05-13','2013-06-09','2013-06-10','2013-08-04','2013-08-26','2013-09-02','2013-09-03','2013-11-23','2013-12-02','2013-12-13','2013-12-21','2014-01-21','2014-03-22','2014-03-31','2014-05-09','2014-05-17','2014-05-19','2014-06-15','2014-06-16','2014-08-10','2014-08-25','2014-09-01','2014-09-02','2014-11-22','2014-12-01','2014-12-12','2014-12-20','2015-01-20','2015-03-21','2015-03-30','2015-05-08','2015-05-16','2015-05-18','2015-06-14','2015-06-15','2015-08-19','2015-08-24','2015-09-07','2015-09-08','2015-11-21','2015-11-30','2015-12-11','2015-12-19','2016-01-19')
EndDate<-c('2009-08-23','2009-09-06','2009-09-07','2009-11-20','2009-11-29','2009-12-10','2009-12-18','2010-01-18','2010-03-19','2010-03-28','2010-05-06','2010-05-14','2010-05-16','2010-06-12','2010-06-13','2010-08-07','2010-08-22','2010-09-05','2010-09-06','2010-11-19','2010-11-28','2010-12-09','2010-12-17','2011-01-17','2011-03-18','2011-03-27','2011-05-05','2011-05-13','2011-05-15','2011-06-11','2011-06-12','2011-08-06','2011-08-21','2011-09-04','2011-09-05','2011-11-18','2011-11-27','2011-12-08','2011-12-16','2012-01-16','2012-03-16','2012-03-25','2012-05-03','2012-05-11','2012-05-13','2012-06-09','2012-06-10','2012-08-04','2012-08-26','2012-09-02','2012-09-03','2012-11-16','2012-11-25','2012-12-13','2012-12-20','2013-01-13','2013-01-20','2013-01-21','2013-03-15','2013-03-24','2013-05-02','2013-05-10','2013-05-12','2013-06-08','2013-06-09','2013-08-03','2013-08-25','2013-09-01','2013-09-02','2013-11-22','2013-12-01','2013-12-12','2013-12-20','2014-01-20','2014-03-21','2014-03-30','2014-05-08','2014-05-16','2014-05-18','2014-06-14','2014-06-15','2014-08-09','2014-08-24','2014-08-31','2014-09-01','2014-11-21','2014-11-30','2014-12-11','2014-12-19','2015-01-19','2015-03-20','2015-03-29','2015-05-07','2015-05-15','2015-05-17','2015-06-13','2015-06-14','2015-08-08','2015-08-23','2015-09-06','2015-09-07','2015-11-20','2015-11-29','2015-12-10','2015-12-18','2016-01-18','3000-01-01')


# create data frames
refstats<-data.frame(Date)
calendar<-data.frame(Semester,StartDate,EndDate)

# convert Date to a Date object for evaluation in nested    ifelse statement
refstats$Date <- as.Date(refstats$Date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
calendar$StartDate <- as.Date(calendar$StartDate, fromat = '%Y-%m-%d')
calendar$EndDate <- as.Date(calendar$EndDate, fromat = '%Y-%m-%d')

# determine semester of each refstats$Date, by reference dataframe containing calendar
# of school year dates.  calendar$EndDate is not really used, because the
# findInterval function defaults to left-closed intervals so only need to use StartDate:
refstats$Semester <- calendar$Semester[ findInterval(refstats$Date, calendar$StartDate)]
```

At first, this yielded an error message *Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Semester", value = c(2L, 2L, 13L,  : 
  replacement has 34 rows, data has 38*

My data has some values that are out of range on both ends for the intervals.  So I added a start interval that goes back to the year 1000, and an end interval that goes up to year 3000.  It works!

Comment: You are comparing numeric values (which is what Date-classed variables are) to character values.

Comment: I have added replacement code at the bottom of my question, with '' removed within ifelse statement.  The code runs, but finds no matching dates - am I still comparing apples and oranges?

Comment: Type `2015-12-19` with no quotes at your console and see what you get.

Comment: well that produces:  1984  but I am no closer to understanding why - obviously I have some beginner's problem

Comment: Your `ifelse` would work just fine if you wrap all your `"2015-08-24"` in `as.Date()`. You need to make them dates.

Comment: Gregor, I recoded as you suggested, now I am back to the same problem I initially had.  I do not at all understand the solution of BondedDust.  I will have approx 70,000 dates in the real dataset, not sure if that is feasible with BondedDust approach, but I understand it so little, I'd rather continue with my ifelse - even if it is less elegant, it may be more user friendly to a begginer!

Comment: The number of dates is not a limiting factor. Once ypu have encoded all the "dividing-Dates" and assembled corresponding names, yu could run a million Dates through that "machine". It's going to be quite a bit faster than the `ifelse` monstrosity you are building. If you wnat to continue with the ifelse strategy you should try it with just a few intervals to get your logic correct; then "scale it up".

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the `findInterval` approach and see if I can understand it.  It is a monstrosity as coded here - you wouldn't have liked it (and neither did R) when I had it all as a single giant ifelse statement.  Apparently my attempts to muscle through with what I already knew must not be the optimal approach should have a lesson for me....

Comment: I didn't add an answer (only a comment) because BondedDust's solution is **much** better. I was just trying to help you understand  why your attempt wasn't working. And listen to his good advice: get a few data points and try with one holiday, then two. Once those are working, then try 70,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logical problems you have not addressed. What about the dates prior to the first date in your ifelse?

```
> dt2009_10 <- scan(what="")
1: '2009-08-24'
2: '2009-09-07'
3: '2009-09-08'
4: '2009-11-21'
5: '2009-11-30'
6: '2009-12-11'
7: '2009-12-19'
8: '2010-01-19'
9: '2010-03-20'
10: '2010-03-29'
11: '2010-05-07'
12: '2010-05-15'
13: '2010-05-17'
14: '2010-06-13'
15: '2010-06-14'
16: '2010-08-08'
17: 
Read 16 items

> nam2009_10 <- c("Fall" , 
+ "Labor Day" , 
+ "Fall" , 
+ "Fall Break" , 
+ "Fall" , 
+ "Fall Finals" , 
+ "Winter Break" , 
+ "Spring" , 
+ "Spring Break" , 
+ "Spring" , 
+ "Spring Finals" , 
+ "Closed" , 
+ "Summer I" , 
+ "Closed" , 
+ "Summer II" , 
+ "Summer Break" )
```

I'm not going to do all the work to construct the multi-year set of values but rather will demonstrate how to avoid using nested `ifelse` statements. The `findInterval` function defaults to left-closed intervals so we can use your beginning set of values which I extracted and put into `dt2009_10`. Then comapre to your Date-classed Date variable and use as an index into the names of intervals that I put into `nam2009_10`:

```
nam2009_10[ findInterval(refstats$Date, as.Date(dt2009_10) ) ]
 [1] "Fall"         "Fall"         "Summer Break" "Labor Day"    "Fall"        
 [6] "Fall Break"   "Fall"         "Fall Finals"  "Winter Break" "Winter Break"
[11] "Spring"       "Spring Break" "Summer I"     "Closed"       "Summer II"   
[16] "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break"
[21] "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break"
[26] "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break"
[31] "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break" "Summer Break"
```

Since I didn't do 2010-11, or later years, all the later dates showed up as Summer Break".

Then it

Comment: In the previous question of OP (on the same topic), I pointed him to [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045753/how-to-classify-a-given-date-time-by-the-season-e-g-summer-autumn) where I used `findInterval`. I still believes that's a "better approach to the problem".

Comment: "A logical problems you have not addressed. What about the dates prior to the first date in your ifelse?"   I thought these would end up being NA values.   I am now trying to understand the `findInterval` approach, and will update my question with the revised code, if I can figure it out.  I do not know what "the previous question of OP" means - perhaps that refers to my previous question? What is OP?

Comment: OP == "original poster". It's newsgroup slang.

Comment: I think I'm close now, perhaps generating an error due to some of the dates in refstats$Date being out of range of my calendar, not sure how to assign these to be = NA

Comment: Thank you Henrik and BondedDust, I got it to work, code nearest bottom of my question has it running.