# Why is there no apply.season in R with xts/zoo?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am working with climate data which I want to split up into seasons (DJF, MAM, JJA and SON) and apply a function to each individual season.
xts offers apply.quarterly but that splits it up into quarters (JFM, AMJ, JAS, OND).

How can I do this seasonally with period.apply? endpoints also only offers quarters and not seasons.

I am using xts and zoo.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Another valuable Q&A's: [Find which season a particular date belongs to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500114/find-which-season-a-particular-date-belongs-to) & [How to classify a given date/time by the season (e.g. summer, autumn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045753/how-to-classify-a-given-date-time-by-the-season-e-g-summer-autumn)