# How do extract the season from dates in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm having trouble extracting seasons from dates in R. I'd like to create a 'season' column. Can someone please help?

Here is the data frame:

```
temp24
```

Here is my tibble:

```
<dttm>                     <dbl>          <dbl>                        <dbl>
 1 2021-01-01 00:00:00      104134.             0                          33.9
 2 2021-01-02 00:00:00       93074.         98604.                         32.9
 3 2021-01-03 00:00:00       87300.         90187.                         32.3
 4 2021-01-04 00:00:00       95548.         91424.                         32.5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is a season?

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500114/find-which-season-a-particular-date-belongs-to

Comment: Hi Dennis, a period in the year- winter, summer, autumn, spring